# Как найти подстроку (заданную в переменной) в строке

Tags: javascript

Необходимо проверить есть ли значение проверочного слова в строке. Но почему-то данный код работает неверно:

```js
var str = " просто. слово ",
    prover_slovo = "слово"
var result = str.match(/prover_slovo/i);
if (result[0].length) {
    console.log(result[0])
}
```

Как исправить?

Comment: а как вы хотите, чтобы оно работало, какой нужен результат?

Comment: почему б не использовать "indexof" ?

Comment: ну я бы хотел просто проверять строку на наличие в ней определённых слов

Comment: очевидно потому, что в этом случае нужно использовать конструктор RegExp, чтобы использовать строку из переменной

Comment: через регулярки надо str.match( new RegExp(prover_slovo, 'i') ) Просто проверить слово лучше через 'Hello World'.indexOf('World') !== -1

Comment: @tcpack4, так делать опасно, если неизвестно откуда приходит значение в `prover_slovo`

Comment: @Grundy он же определил выше.

Comment: @tcpack4, подозреваю, это просто для примера. Плюс стоит добавить обработку строки, если например в ней нужно будет искать символ точку

Comment: нет, на самом деле я незнаю что будет в переменной prover_slovo, поэтому индексОф и не использовал

Comment: всем спасибо разобрался!

Comment: @Grundy если так, то да, регулярки должны быть статичны и не должны приходить из вне.

Answer (score 3):

Если вас интересует наличие подстроки в строке, то можно использовать конструкцию indexOf, если подстрока есть, то результат будет больше, чем -1:

```
var string = 'просто. слово';
var result = string.indexOf("Мир"); //result = -1
var result = string.indexOf("просто"); //result = 0, так как вхождение подстроки начинается с начала строки символа
var result = string.indexOf("рост"); //result = 1, так как вхождение подстроки начинается с 1 символа
```